# Extracting information from input elements in an xml format

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

Here is an example of the input text tags in xml,

```
<Root>
  <Items>
    <Content>
      <ContentControl>
        <Grid>
          <Image Tag="And" ToolTip="And"/>
          <TextBox Tag="Num1">12</TextBox>
          <TextBox Tag="Num2">15</TextBox>
        </Grid>
      </ContentControl>
    </Content>
    <Content>
      <ContentControl>
        <Grid>
          <Image Tag="Button Pressed" ToolTip="Button Pressed"/>
          <ComboBox IsDropDownOpen="False" Text="4" Tag="Num2">
            <ComboBoxItem>0</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">4</ComboBoxItem>
          </ComboBox>
        </Grid>
      </ContentControl>
    </Content>
  </Items>
</Root>
```

I need to read the inputs entered into the text boxes and combo boxes individually using C#.

How can I determine which input element is which from reading the tags attached to them ?and how do I extract the data from the textbox and combobox inputs respectively, once I have determined the input data I want to extract?

For example, from the text box tagged 'Num1', I want to extract the value 12 and from the combo box from the selected item I want to extract the value 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the ultimate goal you're trying to achieve.

Anyway, this demonstrates how to achieve what mentioned in "*For example*" section of this question. This use `XDocument` and [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) query to select value 12 from the text box tagged 'Num1' and value 4 from combo box selected item :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path_to_xml_file.xml");
var textBoxValue 
    = (string) doc.
                XPathSelectElement("/Root/Items/Content/ContentControl/Grid/TextBox[@Tag='Num1']");
var comboBoxValue 
    = (string)doc
                .XPathSelectElement("/Root/Items/Content/ContentControl/Grid/ComboBox[@Tag='Num2']/ComboBoxItem[@IsSelected='True']");
```

**UPDATE :**

in case you have default namespace declared somewhere in the XML, the XML element where default namespace declared and all it's descendants considered in default namespace. But in the other side, all elements in XPath query having no prefix considered has no namespace.

So to bridge that difference, you need to

1. add prefix declaration pointing to default namespace url
2. add that prefix to an `XmlNamespaceManager`
3. use that prefix when selecting elements in default namespace
4. and pass the `XmlNamespaceManager` as second parameter of `XPathSelectElement` method

For example, assuming that default namespace declared from `<Root>` element  :

```
var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
var textBoxValue
    = (string)doc.
                XPathSelectElement(
                    "/ns:Root/ns:Items/ns:Content/ns:ContentControl/ns:Grid/ns:TextBox[@Tag='Num1']"
                    , namespaceManager);
```

Comment: I am sorry if I confused you, but you actually answered my question :). I am presently getting a null being registered in the extracted value from the textbox and combobox and there is a value in both. Do you think you know what can cause that?

Comment: does your actual xml file has default namespace? the one without prefix, so it is like `xmlns="any url address here"`

Comment: The file I am using has a different namespace from the project I am running it on. Project using the file has a name space 'Test WPF' and the control content tag has a name space of
`xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:dd="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner;assembly=DiagramDesigner"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`
Do you think that is the problem?

Comment: definitely, that a classic problem when dealing with XML having default namespace. Check my updated answer for explanation.

Comment: You my friend are a god sent, much thanks for all of the assistance. This was the cure I needed for week's worth of headaches trying to figure out how to do this. Again, Thank You!!!